# Difference between using .html() and .contents()

Tags: jquery, html

What's the difference between using these two jQuery snippets?

```
.append( $(this).contents() );
// and
.append( $(this).html() );
```

Comment: did you read the docs?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: everybody seems to be ignoring the `.append()` part of the question.

Comment: @mkoryak - Yes.  In theory, they accomplish the same thing.  But I don't know which function gives browsers less chance to botch the data.  (For ex., IE's .innerHTML function will filter out <html>, <title>, and <head> elements when using the jQuery( html [, ownerDocument] ) syntax.

Comment: @BrandonLebedev: No, they do very different things. Not the same at all. Your filtering of those elements is another good difference though.

Comment: Note that Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: @TimothyAaron - using either function, or just one?

Comment: @BrandonLebedev Sorry, with `.html()`.

Comment: @TimothyAaron - Got it.  So unless I need to manipulate "HTML" as a string, using `.html()` is just a backwards implementation of `.contents()`?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`.contents()` returns the elements, thus moving them. http://api.jquery.com/contents/

`.html()` returns a string, thus copying the elements. http://api.jquery.com/html/

Comment: 32bitkid is right. The `.append()` part of the question does matter. More specifically, for `.contents()` it will effectively move those elements, for `.html()` it will copy those elements.

Comment: @TimothyAaron I would suppose that copying the HTML of the elements is the same as a shallow copy, not a deep copy (which would bring event handlers and so forth along). Thus if copying the handlers is desired, `.contents().clone()` should be used.

Comment: Also note that Internet Explorer sometimes leaves off the quotes around attribute values if they contain only alphanumeric characters.

Comment: Why does `.contents()` "cut" instead of "copy"?  Does it only work that way when used with `.append()`?

Comment: Because `.contents()` returns the actually elements, so `.append`ing them somewhere else puts them where you ask. (Yes, it just works that way with a function that injects elements.)

Answer (score 28):

Yes, they're entirely different

- `.contents()` gives you a jQuery object containing all the ***child DOM nodes*** of the element.
- `.html()` gives you ***a string of HTML*** rendered from the descendant nodes of the element.

So when you `.append()` the `contents()`, you're relocating the nodes to a new location.

When you `.append()` the `.html()`, you're generating new nodes from the HTML string.

---

Keep in mind that on the client side, ***there is no HTML***. You only have the DOM.

Considering that...

- ...when you do `.html()`, what's happening is that all the descendant DOM nodes are being analyzed, and an HTML string *is being created* and returned.
- ...when you do `.html('<b>some HTML content</b>')`, the HTML string itself isn't added to the DOM, but rather the string is *parsed*, and new DOM nodes are generated, which are then added to the DOM.

---

Based on a comment about *cutting and copying*, it sounds as though you still think you're working with the original HTML string sent from the server.

You're not.

You're working with JavaScript objects *(well, host objects)* that are nested within each other to form a hierarchy of objects *(parents, children, grandchildren, etc)*. You can relocate a section of that hierarchy to another location within the hierarchy.

*This hierarchy of elements is called the DOM, or Document Object Model.*

Unfortunately, since jQuery's `.append()` accepts an HTML string, it adds to the illusion that you're actually dealing with HTML markup instead of objects.

So I'll state it again...

- `.html()` ***generates a new HTML string***. When you give the string to `.append()`, it will ***create new nodes*** based on that string, and insert them.
- `.contents()` simply ***selects the existing nodes***, and inserts them. Since a node can't be in two locations at the same time, the nodes are relocated to the location in the DOM where they are being appended.

Comment: +1 for answering what `.append()` will do when dealing with a string vs a collection of nodes.

Comment: So, (in theory), does `.contents()` use less processing?

Comment: @BrandonLebedev: Those questions are always relative to the implementation, but to make a broad statement, I'd say *yes*. Remember that on the client side, you don't have *any* HTML to work with. So when you do `.html()` it analyzes the DOM, and *creates* the string of HTML. When you do `.html('<b>some HTML content</b>')`, it parses the string, and generates new DOM nodes.